# Currency Exchanger

Tags: java

I am trying  to write a code that will exchange between AED,MYR,USD. I got to the following code and I cant fix the error.

It looked like the system.in isn't closing so I wrote the `inclose()`. But I still get the same results.

My problem might be something else and am not seeing it.

**EDIT**: this is the current code with changes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CurrencyConverter
{
     protected static long amount;
     static long Namount ;
     static int commesion;

     static String to;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    CurrencyConverterM MSg=new CurrencyConverterM();
    CurrencyConverterM account1 = new CurrencyConverterM( );
     String from ;
    for(int i=0 ;i<3; i++)
     {
        System.out.println("Please enter your currency (USD, AED, or MYR only): ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
        from = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What currency do you want?: ");
        String to = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How much you want to convert?: ");
        amount= in.nextLong();
                //in.close();

    if ("USD".equals(from)) {
        amount=((long) (amount*0.27));
        amount=account1.converter(to, amount);
    }
    else if ("MYR".equals(from)) {
        amount=((long) (amount * 1.14));
        amount =account1.converter(to, amount);
    }
    else {
        if(mmount >= 900) {
            Namount = (amount-50);
            commesion =50;

        }
        else 
        {
            Namount = (amount - 10);
            commesion = 10;
        }
    }
        System.out.println(MSg.getMsg());

}

    }
```

}

the output should be as follows.
  asking for current currency:
  asking to what currency u want it:
  asking about  the amount.
am converting any amount to AED so I make it the main unit, then converting to the wished unit.
***EDIT***

```
     public class CurrencyConverterM extends CurrencyConverter
     {
        long am;
     @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
   long converter (String to,long amount)
   {

    if ("MYR".equals(to)) {
        am=(super.amount*=0.88);

    }
    else if ("MYR".equals(to)) {
        am=(super.amount*=3.7);

    }
    return am ;
}



@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public  String getMsg()
{
    return ("Thank you. The converted amount is "+(super.amount) + ". We will take" +super.commesion + " commission, and you will get "+ super.Namount);
}
```

}

before it didn't read the user's input, now its not converting the values.
I tried to print out my vales after each calculation but it looks like that the variable am is not being calculated correctly and its being multiplied by a 0 or divided by one ( the last result is always 0 ) but the amount that is in the main class is not 0 and its not converted to AED as well.

So I am getting this :Thank you. The converted amount is 0.0   1000.0. We will take50 commission, and you will get 0.0

Comment: You can't fix which error?  here is one major problem: from=="MYR" you can't compare the value of Objects like this, you need to use the equals method

Comment: **DO NOT** keep creating `Scanner`s and using them for one input and then closing them.  Create **one** `Scanner` object near the start of `main`, use it each time you need input, and only close it at the very end of `main` (or just don't close it at all).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: And note: it is **really** bad to fix one error in your code (the wrong string comparison), but still **not at all** telling us what you still convince as **error** with your code.

Comment: sorry for that, I will edit it now.                                                                                        and will edit the post soon so it has the properties of a  minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `scanner.nextLine() (in.nextLine())` and not `in.toString()`

Also you can use the same scanner and not to create 3 different scanners.

See the following part of your code updated with one Scanner (in):

```
    System.out.println("Please enter your currency (USD, AED, or MYR only): ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
    from = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What currency do you want?: ");
    String to = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How much you want to convert?: ");
    amount= in.nextLong();
    System.out.println(from + " " + to);
    in.close();
```

by doing in.nextLine() you read the next line of user input.

From java 8 javadocs:

> nextLine
>
> public String nextLine()
>
> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line.
>
> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a
>   line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line
>   to skip if no line separators are present.

The above will solve the issue that no input is read by your code.

Later you will have issues comparing the String user entered:

`from=="USD"` should be changed to `"USD".equals(from)`

Tip: Prefer to use "String".equals(variable) to avoid null pointer exceptions when variable is null.

Comment: actually, by calling next, you read the next token. Did you mean nextLine() ?

Comment: Thank you @Stultuske. Answer updated. next() could also be used, however it iterates between whitespaces (tokens). In any case a correct implementation should include checks and validations for correct input.

Comment: yep thanx for that, didn't know about "Strings".equals(variable)

Answer (score 0):

String comparison is wrong.

`from=="MYR"` should be `from.equals("MYR")` rather I would recommend `equalsIgnoreCase` which is not case sensitive.

Comment: I would recommend to call the equals on the String literal

Comment: my comment was not about equals vs equalsIgnoreCase, it was about from.equals("MYR") vs "MYR".equals(from). It's just following best practices that might avoid NPE's in certain circumstances

Comment: that really helped but now am stuck with another problem... for some reason it wont show me the right converted amount.

Comment: @ZakariaAbouShaer Note: this is not a free debugging. A) first try to debug your code yourself, and only when that doesnt work then B) write up a clear question that clearly points your current problem.

Comment: I know its not a free debugging site, am a student and am trying to learn java in an object oriented way, tried debugging myself and didn't do well .

Comment: you can debug using ide, iterate over each step, this will help you